# Xpath: select an element of specific type which is sibling to the selected element

Tags: xpath

Here is an excerpt of my xml:

```
<div class="0001">
    <label title="Label1">Label1:</label>
</div>
<div class="0002">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

I know how to select the "Label1" label. I need to select an input of text type. Class names are generated in a random way and changes after each session. So it's only possible to refer to label title and an input type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
'//div[label[@title="Label1"]]/following-sibling::div/input[@type="text"]'
```

select a `<div>` which contains a `<label>` which itself has a `title` attribute with value `Label1`, then look for an `<input>` with `type` "text" in the `<div>` siblings of this former `<div>`